# Linux command to give all files in a directory a file extension

Tags: linux, bash

I came up with this:

```
for i in *; 
do input=`echo $i|sed -e 's/[ ]/\\\ /g'`; 
output=`echo $input".mp3"`; 
mv $input $output; done
```

Its very close, but it mv complains:

> mv: invalid option -- '\'

I don't quite get why it won't work if I try echoing $input or $output they both seem to properly escape all the spaces in the file names and nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are massively over-complicating this with your use of `sed` (and `echo`)...

You are trying to escape space characters in file names, but you really just need to enclose the filename in quotation marks. You can simply do...

```
for i in *; do
    mv "${i}" "${i}.mp3"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. Its seemed like what I had was to complicated. :-)

Comment: Of course, this won't work if the filenames have quotation marks in them ;-P. And because bash uses a space to separate array elements, filenames with spaces will break it badly.

Answer (score 9):

`find . -type f -exec mv "{}" "{}.mp3" \;`

Comment: This changes files in subdirs as well which may or may not be what the OP wants. Example in question does not traverse dirs. to limit to current dir use the `-maxdepth` option.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter and safer :

```
for i; do
    mv -- "${i}" "${i}.mp3"
done
```

=)

**`--`** takes care of files starting with a dash

and **`for i in *`** is shortened by **`for i`**

**Use more quotes**: they are vital. Also, learn the difference between `'`, `"` and <kbd>`</kbd>. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words. ( sentence stolen from IRC freenode #bash )

Comment: Nope, see "mv $input $output; done" should be "mv "$input" "$output"; done"

Comment: I think you are confusing Simon the Cat's question (I only corrected the misspelling in the title) with my answer (which does uses neither $input nor $output).

Comment: Doh ! Yes, that's "Simon The Cat" question, sorry  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[rename](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Linux/rename.1.html)**, it makes these things very simple:

```
rename 's/$/.mp3/' *
```

Comment: You should take care of different versions of rename. This one ine the perl one. If the command "file $(type -p rename)" displays "ELF", you have the wrong one ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *; do mv -- ${i}{,.mp3};done
```